# Why are Born-Haber enthalpy calculations inaccurate for transition metal compounds?

Tags: enthalpy

A senior high/secondary school level exam question is about discrepancies between calculated and empirical enthalpies of formation. It asks why a discrepancy “usually” exists for d-block compounds such as copper (II) chloride.

For something like AgCl or AlCl3 the answer is covalent character. But that’s not true for CuCl2, is it?